# custom ActionBar shape android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to create a custom  actionBar with a different shape (not rectangular) as shown on the image below, does anyone knows point me on the right direction?

[image: how you can see in the picture]

Comment: I doubt that's an action bar. It's probably just part of the UI of the activity, and they have disabled the action bar.

Comment: If you problem is solved, might I ask why don't you accept an answer ?

Comment: @AlexanderMalakhov sorry I forgot to accept it 2 years ago

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At this point, it is no longer an ActionBar. Something like that would be a custom View.
It is missing a number of key components of the ActionBar such as the application icon and back arrow, and is lacking all of an ActionBar's styling.

You can create a [completely custom View class](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html) and use that, or make a [reusable layout](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html) and include it wherever needed using an include tag.

Comment: thanks worked very well, the only bad thing about this solution was the 800 lines that I had to write to create it!